# Список запущенных процессов на виртуальной машине (удаленной)

Tags: c#, .net, виртуальная-машина

Список всех запущенных процессов на компьютере получаю вот так:

```
static void AllInfoProcess()
{
    var myProcess = from proc in Process.GetProcesses()
                    orderby proc.Id
                    select proc;
    Console.WriteLine("\n*** Текущие процессы ***\n");
    foreach (var p in myProcess)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-> PID: {0}\tName: {1}", p.Id, p.ProcessName);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Всего процессов запущено {0}", myProcess.Count());
}
```

Мне надо получить список процессов на удаленной машине.
В мой случае, я установил виртуальную машину (VirtualBox), настроил тип подключения между моей ОС и виртуальной машиной "Виртуальный адаптер хоста".
И вроде как если воспользоваться тем же методом, только с параметром `ComputerName` выведет все процессы запущенные там, но как бы я не писал, выводит процессы с локальной ОС.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses("ComputerName");
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне вывести процессы, запущенные на удаленной машине?

Comment: @AK
У меня только компьютер и вот виртуалку сделал(
Проверил, пингуются в обе стороны, основная винда 7 и на виртуалке 7.
Я чтобы не вводил в скобках(имя) выводит процессы с текущей ОС все равно(( возможно настроить надо как-то виртуалку еще?

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, у вас вопрос по .NET Framework или .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

Именно так, как вы написали.

У меня ваш пример прекрасно срабатывает для первой попавшейся виртуалки в локальной сети.

В доках есть [замечания](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x8b2hzk8(v=vs.110).aspx) по поводу win98 и прочих старых ОС, это не ваш случай, верно?

Но вероятнее всего, проблема вызвана тем, что вы пытаетесь подключиться к ОС внутри виртуалки и не попадаете.

Проверьте, доступна ли виртуалка снаружи: можете ли вы пингануть виртуалку с хост-машины. Можете ли вы под тем пользователем, под которым запущена программа подключиться к другому компьютеру с правами администратора, например, к c$ -- это будет очень показательно, так как у вас если не домен, как у меня то вы можете просто не получить нужных прав на удалённой машине.

Вполне возможно, что виртуальная машина делит с хост-машиной IP-адрес (в VMWare такой режим сети точно есть, в VirtualBox тоже может есть).

Попробуйте соседнюю машину в сети проверить, а не виртуалку. Возможно, у вас домашняя сетка и кроме своего компа есть ещё машины родственников.

Comment: А что значит делит IP-адрес?
у хоста ip 192.168.56.1
а у виртуалки ip 192.168.56.101
и я вроде все делаю правильно, как выше написал, но постоянно выводит процессы только хоста(

Comment: Я сейчас подключил ноутбук к роутеру, пишу название компьютера и все равно выдает поцессы которые на моем компьютере а не которые там((

Comment: @Алексей Вы уверены, что это процессы основного компьютера, а не удалённого? Они же очень похожи, запустите на удалённом компьютере такой процесс, которого нет на основном (хоть блокнот) и проверьте.

Comment: Проверял конечно((
на хосте запущено 150-160 процессов, а на ноутбуке 100-110, я в конце просто вывожу количество всех процессов и оно видно где сколько
а возможно надо как-то где-то еще создавать подключение к гостевому компу?

Comment: @Алексей проверьте возможно ли подключение и запрос процессов с помощью утилит Sysibternals, а именно pslist. Если подключение проходит нормально и Вы получаете перечень процессов - то все ок. Но учтите, что обязательно нужно запустить службы "сервер" (lanmanserver) и "удаленный реестр" (remoteregistry)